# How to list Pods events based on Pod Labels in kubernetes client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl, client-go, kubernetes-go-client

I want to fetch the pod events by using the Pod label in Kubernetes client-go,

I had tried the below code but not working by passing the namepsace nd podname ,

```
namespace := "test"
podNameInital := "testpods"
labelSelector := metav1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels: map[string]string{"test/label": "devtest1"}}
fieldSelector := fmt.Sprintf("involvedObject.name=%s", podNameInital) 
events1, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Events(namespace).List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{
        FieldSelector: fieldSelector,
         TypeMeta:      metav1.TypeMeta{Kind: "Pod"},
    })

for _, item := range events1.Items {
    fmt.Println(item)
}
```

please help me to fix this.

Can You help me to get the pod events only with the help of the label name? actually, I will be having only a label name, so need to get the matching pod with this label and then need to get the events from that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't because Events don't include Pod labels.

In your example, you should receive an `EventList` containing events where `metav1.TypeMeta{Kind: "Pod"}` and `involvedObject.name=testpods` in namespace `test` but, note that the events **don't** include the Pod labels.

You can prove this to yourself by enumerating the `EventList` without the `labelSelector`:

```golang
fieldSelector := fmt.Sprintf("involvedObject.name=%s", podNameInital)
events, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Events(namespace).List(
    context.TODO(),
    metav1.ListOptions{
        FieldSelector: fieldSelector,
        TypeMeta:      metav1.TypeMeta{Kind: "Pod"},
    },
)

log.Printf("%d events", len(events.Items))
b, err := json.MarshalIndent(events, "", "  ")
if err != nil {
    log.Println("unable to marshal Events")
}

log.Println(string(b))
```

Comment: Can You help me to get the pod events only with the help of the label name?

actually I will be having only a lable name, so need to get the matching pod with this label and then need to get the events from that.

Comment: Please don't change questions. The answer I provided answered your question as-was. Instead of changing the question, you should ask a new question. You've not accepted my previous answer and, if I answer the revised question, chances are you won't accept my answer and may revise your question yet again.

Comment: You will need to enumerate the Pods using your label selector. From the list of Pods that results, you'll need to list events by those Pods' names. Kubernetes selectors are intersections (`AND` only) and so -- I think you can't -- issue one `List` for a union (`OR`) query (which you'd need to select on multiple Pod names). You'll need to call the `List` method on Events for each Pod.